# How to get access JTable from another class java

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have three classes one is a `JFrame` and other two are `JPanel` . The class A has a `JTable` and i need to access the `JTabel` selected item in another class. Is that possible to get the selected  item using the model? Or how to access the `JTable` in class B?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: *I have three classes one is a JFrame and other two are JPanel"* It is likely that none of those classes should extend components.

Comment: I think you have a class that extends JFrame and two classes that extend JPanel? It is however quite important to know how they are related to each other? Can you provide us with some source code that explains this relation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because you are working with a Swing GUI does not change any of the rules of good object-oriented program techniques. You will need to give classes provide means of communicating with each other, perhaps by getter or setter methods, but you will want to limit this communication to be done with the least exposure necessary to maintain encapsulation/data hiding.

Comment: True we can use the Getter setter but Without creating an instance it is not possible right?

Comment: @Ramesh: don't confuse "creating an instance" with having a reference to an object. The latter is the important thing.

Comment: @Ramesh: often it's getting that reference that confuses many newbies. You will need to have references to any object that you want to call a method off of, and that means not creating a new instance at the time you want to call the method but rather calling the method off of a reference stored in a reference variable that the class holds.

Comment: You have to determine if passing the table as an argument to the panel/frame or use panel.setTable or if needed make that table static, that will depend on your architecture, once I had to make a class with access to any part of the gui, since there were only one instance of every object in the gui, I convert them to static, where is the table supposed to be at the beginning, jPanel, jFrame? are there any connections in the definition of those classes? Don't worry, you can pass args, now let's try to do it a little bit clean.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the selected item in the JTable in any class, including class B, that has a reference to the JTable, its ListSelectionModel, or something else that exposes the selected item.

For example, if class B has a reference to class A -- and class A has a JTable -- then class B could ask class A for the currently selected item.

Answer (score -2):

Please , your jTable variable accees modifier replace as a